# Tikzscale does not scale a figure when it contains addplot3

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-external, tikzscale

I wanted to implement a 3d-figure containing stacked 2d-layers, with an example below:
[image]
I used the following code, with a main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.dat}
    x y
    0 0
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    5 5
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{file2.dat}
    x y
    0 0
    1 4
    2 6
    3 8
    4 10
    5 12
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz-cache/]
\tikzset{external/force remake}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize}
    },
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=1,
        draw=black!50!black,
        fill=white,
        mark=none,
    },
    y axis/.append style={align=center}}
\tikzset{Line Label/.style={font=\footnotesize,scale=2}}
\newcommand{\figurefontsize}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{sub.tikz}
        \caption{Image I}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the tikz-file `sub.tikz`:

```
\pgfplotstableread{file1.dat}{\tablea}
\pgfplotstableread{file2.dat}{\tableb}
\tikzsetnextfilename{sub}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0, ymax=30,
        xmin=0, xmax=5,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        grid=major,
        legend entries={\(y_1\),\(y_2\),\(y_1+y_2\)},
        legend pos = north west
        ]
        % Select appropriate columns
        
        \addplot3 [area plot, ultra thick, red] table [x=x, y expr=2, z=y] {\tableb}\closedcycle;
        \addplot3 [area plot, ultra thick, blue] table [x=x, y expr=1, z=y] {\tablea} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now, when compiling, the figure does not change size, regardless if I use

```
\includegraphics[width=5\linewidth]{sub.tikz}
```

or

```
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{sub.tikz}
```

The same approach works if I have 2d-data. Why does it fail for the current approach?